# Run an exotic shortcut in CMD (windows mystery)

Tags: vpn, cmd.exe

123.lnk

Shortcut properties:

Target : {BA126AD7-ETC-LIKE-SERIAL-NUMBER}

This basically runs my vpn but it can't be launched via cmd.
When i do:

**Start "" "123.lnk"**

the command goes through and nothing happens.
Unlike when you a launch a shortcut for exe or something else common.
To test your self - make a shortcut for your lan card - Disable said lan card. Running this particular shortcut via cmd is a no go. Using the shortcut manually will enable it.

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted works fine here (win7 sp1 x64). On the offchance that your actual command (path + shortcut) has embedded spaces or other characters that require quoting, try this instead:

```
start "" "123.lnk"
```

The first quoted argument of `start` is always taken to mean the window title.

Comment: Make a shortcut to your lan card. Disable said lan card. Using the shortcut will enable it. Disable again - good luck ever running the shortcut via cmd. If i run a shortcut for explorer or winamp it will run. This kind of shortcut we are looking at - wont.

Comment: @helena4 Sorry, I can't quite connect what you wrote here with what you asked originally. It would help if you gave a step-by-step of what you are doing and what doesn't work.

Comment: Whatever are you talking about - I just gave you an example of what to do to try your theory for your self - without even needing a vpn setup.

Comment: @helena4 Sorry again, I have no idea what you are talking about. You originally submitted that running a shortcut to open a VPN connection via "start" doesn't work for you. It surely does for me. I proposed a (fairly common) reason why your "start" command may fail. If that doesn't apply, feel free to ignore. Or, if you have additional information, please post it with full details.

Answer (score 0):

Buhahahha, what made it half work was a pause.
if you add **pause** at the bottom it runs.
Otherwise the prompt opens does nothing or does not complete and closes.
And that works ONLY if you've run the lnk manually at least once.

This will run

```
start "" 123.lnk
pause
```

This wont run

```
start "" 123.lnk
```

phahahaha - dat vindows

Comment: `cd d:` will display the current directory on drive D. If you want to actually change the current directory you need `cd /d D:` or `pushd D:`. Replace D: with D:\  to change to the root of D:\ instead of whatever the current directory might be on it. As for the final `pause` all it does is keep the console open until you press a key (assuming you run the batch with `start` or double-click). Everything before it executes exactly the same with or without the `pause`.

Comment: I can run a video for you if you don't trust this is the way it goes down. Unfortunately this is not the complete solution.

Comment: I am not disputing anything in particular. Just pointing that `cd f:` does nothing useful as written (have a look at `cd /?`). Also, that commands in a batch file are not affected by what comes *after* them. Try to replace `start "" 123.lnk` with `start "new console" cmd.exe` for example, and see what happens with vs. without the `pause`.

Comment: Same thing-  your new console window runs but the link doesn't run. And i've discovered the pause is half the remedy. It doesn't run even with it unless the link has been run at least once manually before.